# Project references in TypeScript 3 with separate `outDir`

Tags: typescript

I'd like to make use of the project references features in TypeScript 3.1.
The directory structure of my project originally looks like this after the compilation:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── a.ts
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── A
│   │   │   └── a.js
│   │   └── Shared
│   │       └── shared.js
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── Shared
    ├── dist
    │   └── shared.js
    ├── shared.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

Contents of the `Shared` directory:

`shared.ts`:

```
export const name = "name";
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "outDir": "dist",                        
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Contents of the `A` directory:

`a.ts`:

```
import { name } from "../Shared/shared"; 

console.log(name);
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

And I could successfully run it by running `node dist/A/a.js` in the A directory.

What I didn't like about this was that everything was getting copied into A's output directory. I thought project references are here to fix this problem.

To enable project references, I added the following line to `Shared/tsconfig.json`.

```
"composite": true
```

And the following to `A/tsconfig.json`:

```
"references": [
  { "path": "../Shared" }
]
```

Now when I compile, the directory structure is like the following, which is what I expected:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── a.ts
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── a.js
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── Shared
    ├── dist
    │   ├── shared.d.ts
    │   └── shared.js
    ├── shared.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

However, when I run the `node dist/a.js` in the `A` directory, I get the following Error:

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../Shared/shared'
```

The reason is that in the generated `a.js` file, the reference to the imported module is not resolved properly:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var shared_1 = require("../Shared/shared");
console.log(shared_1.name);
```

Is there a way to get it working without putting all output files into the same directory?

Or, is there a better way to organize my project to make use of project references?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, getting relative import paths to work for both your source files and your output files is a pain.  The [official recommendation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#structuring-for-relative-modules), if I understand it correctly, is to set up a master output directory for the entire composite project and have `Shared` and `A` subdirectories inside it, so the source files and output files can have the same relative layout.  I don't know if that's what you meant you didn't want to do.

The only other option I know of is to have each component import the other components (in your case, you just have `A` importing `Shared`) using non-relative imports that point to output files (i.e., `A/a.ts` would import a path like `Shared/dist/shared`).  Since you are using non-relative imports, the same import path appearing in either a source file or the corresponding output file resolves to the same target output file.  Imports will not resolve in your IDE until you've built the composite project: this is a [known limitation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#caveats-for-project-references).  Since [`tsc` doesn't rewrite imports](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479), you'll need to set up your runtime environment and/or use a bundler to handle the non-relative imports and, if necessary, set the `baseUrl` and `paths` TypeScript compiler options to match.

I'll be happy to help you through the details of either approach if needed; just let me know where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your answer and confirming my findings. I didn't want to change the out folders of the existing projects, but I guess it's better than the second option. I think I'll try the first approach.

Comment: With the first approach, I now have problems with node modules, because they are defined in each project, I guess node cannot find them when I try to run the application from the master output directory. Any idea on that?

Comment: I don't have a great solution; the project references support is very new and the TypeScript team clearly hasn't thought through all the usage scenarios yet.  You can always set `NODE_PATH`, or you can try a tool such as lerna or yarn workspaces.  How did this work in your previous setup where everything was copied to A's output directory?

Comment: I'll look into lerna and yarn workspaces, thanks for the pointer. We have npm scripts in each project for running the application like `node dist/A/a.js`. Previously it was working, I guess because the `node_modules` directory is just there next to the `dist`. But now that I created a master output directory, `node ../dist/A/src/a.js` complains about not finding some modules. Indeed `NODE_PAHT` is a solution, if I specify the node path to the current `node_modules` in `A`, it works. Would haven be great if this project references were working without changing the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

> The official recommendation, if I understand it correctly, is to set up a master output directory for the entire composite project and have Shared and A subdirectories inside it, so the source files and output files can have the same relative layout.

[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731590/2425556) is great. Following up on the comment above, here is one way to reconfigure `A` and `Shared` so the imported module works properly.

`A/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist/A",
    "strict": true
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../Shared" }
  ]
}
```

`Shared/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../A/dist/Shared",
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

The project structure after `tsc --build`:

[image: The project structure after build]

To run `A`, call `node dist/A/a.js`.